# jsdoc to auto use description field

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have an object like this:

```
resource.foo= {
  name: "Foo",
  desc: "Some description"
}
```

I find myself writing:

```
/**
 * Some description
 */
resource.foo= {
  name: "Foo",
  desc: "Some description"
}
```

Anyway to get the desc field automatically without copying and pasting?

Comment: @baboo It looks like he wants to automatically use the `desc` value from the object to create a description in the jsdoc comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to do it, with a keybonding.  Using an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": [
      "editor.action.jumpToBracket",
      "editor.action.selectToBracket",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "editor.action.insertLineBefore"
    ],
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "return `/**\n * ` + ${CLIPBOARD}.desc  + `\n */`",
      "}$$",
    ],
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  }
}
```

You can run javascript in the replace, and yours is pretty easy:

`${CLIPBOARD}.desc` since the clipboard will be the object.

[image: jsdoc with description from object]

Note the cursor must be somewhere inside the object - that is, within the brackets/braces.

Comment: Love it, pretty nice. How about handling edits to the desc so that it updates instead of inserting a new one?

Comment: Looking forward to cursors at other positions.

Comment: What would be your preferred starting cursor position (some might not be possible)?

Comment: Ideally there's no limit, I can put it anywhere in the object and it'll just do it.

Comment: I edited the answer - it should work now if the cursor is anywhere **inside** the object - inside its braces.

Comment: You asked about updates to `desc`.  There is no way to do that with my extension.  You would have to write an extension that watched for file changes to the `desc` field.  Maybe with another keybinding (a different `replace`) the `desc` could be selected first and overwritten, I am not sure.  Easier just to select both of them with `Ctrl+D` and make your changes in both places simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds impossible to me. But if all you need is to show the description in VS Code's hints,  here is the closest possible solution I could come up with:

```js
const resource = {}

const desc = 'Some description'

resource.foo= {
  name: "Foo",
  /** @type {desc} */ desc,
}
```

First declare `desc` as a constant, and you'll be able to reference the constant type. Now you should be able to see the description shows in VS Code's type hints:

[image]

When you are trying to type `resource.foo.desc` you'll also see the description:

[image]